# How to swap special value of array using php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$a = [1,9,8,7,6,5]
```

I want to swap value in such way that if there is a `1`, it should swap with next value.

i.e output should be:

```
$b = [9,1,8,7,6,5]
```

Comment: What you've tried to so far

Comment: Are you sure that it is what you need ? By repeatedly swapping 1 will be put to an end of array in your example. So this makes me think that you want an array sort in decreasing order instead. Can this be true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this work easily using loop

```
$arr = [1,9,8,7,6,5];
foreach($arr as $key=>$item){
    if ($item == 1 && $key < count($arr)-1){
        $arr[$key] = $arr[$key+1];
        $arr[$key+1] = $item;
    }
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/DgrCS)

Comment: You would need to skip the last element.

Comment: What if array $arr = [9,8,7,6,5,1]; like this ?,it generate wrong output